# Can't change customer group when creating order in admin for new customer

Tags: customer-group, magento2.3.3, admin-order-create

I have Magento 2.3.3 and when creating a new order in admin for a new customer I can't change the customer group from dropdown. It just reloads back to the first selection no matter what is selected.

Comment: Check your broser console log for any js error log. Also check any exception log in your Magento 2 log Dir.

Comment: @SupravatM There are no errors appearing in browser console or in in Magento 2 log dir.

Comment: Check in table `select * from customer_group`

Comment: @SupravatM What should I look for there? All groups are there as they should.